# How to set the background color of the return value of a Google Sheets custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I was wondering is someone can help me figure out how to do the following:

1. I have a custom function that returns a number and under a
   specific condition, let say number equals 1, I want the function to
   return the number and color the cell background as well.
2. I have to check the condition within the function and not do a conditional
   formatting from the outside.

any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at Range classe, on [setBackground(string)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String)) or on [setBackgroundRGB(int, int, int)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgroundRGB(Integer,Integer,Integer)) method, which give you the ability to color your range, as you wish.

Edit: Here is a workaround for using setBackground method in your case:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var result = e.range.getValue();

  // Test your condition to change the color
  if(result > 3){

    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    cell.setBackground("red");

  }
}
```

The function will put a red background for all modified value who will be more than 3.

Comment: I've add a example on my answer.

Comment: Thank you Pierre. I call the function from the cell though not from OnEdit(e) maybe that is the problem because when I tried to change the cell number as you suggested it didn't work :( Here is my function   function colorRow_() { 
try {
 
 
// var cell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();

// var column=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn(); 
 



  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    cell.setBackground("red");

           } 
        
 

catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" ;
}
}

Comment: =iscompletetrack(B729,"Teaching Enhancement")  - This is how I call the function from the cell when I have the condition as true I call colorRow_()

Comment: [The name of a custom function cannot end with an underscore (_), which denotes a private function in Apps Script.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: custom functions will not work well for these type of cases.